# Class template overloading, typename and vector of typenames

Tags: c++

is there way to overload my class templates with a single typename and vector of typenames?

Like single typename:

```
template <typename T, ... /*other typedefs same as in second one*/ >
class myClass
{
 myClass(const T & input);
 // ...
}
```

and vector of typenames (probably contains some syntactical errors):

```
template <vector<typename T>, ... >
class myClass<vector<T>, ... >
{
 myClass(vector<T> & input);
 // ...
}
```

Class methods I guess would look like this:

```
template<typename T, ... >
myClass<T, ... >::myClass(const T & input) {/*do something*/}


template<vector<typename T>, ... >
myClass<vector<T>, ... >::myClass(vector<T> & input) {/*do something*/}
```

So simply

```
myClass <string> a; // Should go for first one
myClass <vector<string>> b; // Should go for second one
```

Is there way how to write this to be syntactically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
template <typename T, typename...>
class myClass
{
    myClass(const T& input) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};

template <typename T, typename... R>
class myClass<vector<T>, R...>
{
    myClass(const vector<T>& input) { /*...*/ }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Nice, I like how compiler cant just tell me something like "change template a little bit" but goes for 200lines long story instead :)